# Как заблокировать основное окно, пока открыто окно tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

У меня есть основное окно (MainWindow), на нём есть кнопка, открывающее окно tkinter (root). Как сделать так, чтобы пока открыто окно tkinter, было невозможно взаимодействовать с главным окном?

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from tkinter import *


class MainWindow(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.start_button = None
        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 300, 300)

        self.start_button = QPushButton('Старт', self)
        self.start_button.setGeometry(50, 50, 100, 100)
        self.start_button.clicked.connect(self.tkinter_window)

    def tkinter_window(self):
        root = Tk()
        root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = MainWindow()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Зачем вообще использовать два разных GUI фреймворка одновременно?

Comment: Пока ответ такой: выбрать основной фреймворк, второй убрать, дочерние окна создавать средствами этого фреймворка, и делать их модальными. На tkinter - использовать Toplevel класс для создания диалогового окна и вызывать dialog.grab_set(), чтобы блокировать основное окно, пока открыто диалоговое.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что использовать два графических фреймворка вместе - не целесообразно.